# is paypal's iphone sdk for payment approved by apple?

Tags: iphone, ipad

1)is paypal's iphone sdk for payment approved by apple?

2)Apple guideline says in-app purchase only is accepted by apple.anyother third party payment will be rejected when we integrate it?

3)is appstore having any application which uses paypal iphone sdk?

Comment: This is will give you the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791744/different-options-to-make-payments-inside-an-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction comes down to what you want you're selling. If you're selling digital content that's used on the device (i.e., an upgrade, new content, enhanced features) then you have to use In App Purchase. Sales in the "real world" are not explicitly covered by this rule.

Comment: pls give answer to my all questions..?

Comment: so we can use paypal for real world object.it will also be approved by apple..am i right?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer your other questions. I find it hard to believe that PayPal would create an SDK that does not meet Apple's guidelines, but I don't know for sure. There is a PayPal app, but I don't know whether it uses the same SDK.