# UIWebView to handle payments?

Tags: iphone, payment-gateway

I already do have a payment gateway integrated website and for the iPhone app, I'm wondering is it OK to use a webview to handle payments other than IAP?

Comment: Is your question more "Is UIWebView secure enough to handle payments?" or "Will apple allow me to use UIWebView to handle payments?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Apple’s guidelines make it clear that buying stuff inside an app must be accomplished using Apple’s in-app purchase system, which uses your Apple ID and linked credit card." - from http://www.macworld.com/article/157585/2011/02/inapppurchase.html

If you want to allow a user to purchase something without using Apple IAP, you need to launch your payment website in Safari - like the Kindle app does (see above link).

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make a payment transaction through some other gateway other then IAP in your app it will be rejected. We have an bad experience about this.

Comment: @Elanthiryan, please see the Link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345815/is-paypals-iphone-sdk-for-payment-approved-by-apple)

Comment: @nameless This is will give you the answer for the above
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791744/different-options-to-make-payments-inside-an-application

Answer (score 0):

i hope surely it will be approved by apple.because Lowes iphone application is with webview payment mode in app store.